# Why mezuzah is spelled without the first vav

Tags: mezuzah, spelling-variants, drush

Why in the first paragraph of *Shma* (in [*Devarim* 6:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.9?lang=bi)) it says *mezuzos* (מזזות) without the first *vav* ([the discussion](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Menachot.34a&lang2=en) in *Rashi* here and *Menachos* 34a seems to be about the second *vav* which we have, but we are asking about the *vav* between 2 *zayin* letters).

This is especially strong since in the second paragraph of *Shma* (in [*Devarim* 11:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.20?lang=bi)) it says *mezuzos* (מזוזות) with that *vav* and R' Bachya brings that מזוזה is really *gimatria* אדני, i.e. 65, which only works with the middle *vav* included...

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just note that there are hundreds and thousands of such questions in the Torah. That makes the question broader and harder than ever. And we are no longer expert in when there is such a vav or a yod (gemara Kiddushin).

Comment: @MichoelR i am not saying it is an easy question :-) i rarely use this forum for easy ones... As for your comment on us not being experts in _vavs_ and _yuds_, AFAIK there is no _machlokes_ about spelling these in the _Torah_ in this particular place.

Comment: Note the proper spelling of this word is actually subject to some classical debate

Comment: @DoubleAA could you please elaborate? I went through most of _mikraos gedolos_ and didn't find anything like that (didn't check the Ibn Ezra though)

Comment: @gt6989b See at length in Minchat Shai on Ex 12:7. You might have seen Rashi on your verse, who has it haser in the second spot.

Comment: @magicker72 i did see the _Rashi_ but not the _Minchas Shai_, will take a look _bli neder_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of searching found an expansion of the ideas of Rabbeinu Bachya in Rav Moshe Dovid Valli's *peirush* on *sefer Devarim*. Connecting the ideas from [the first volume](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51277&st=&pgnum=91) to the ones in [the second volume](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51278&st=&pgnum=84), the *mezuza* has 2 different functions (albeit very much related to each other):

1. revealing the Divine presence in your midst is alluded to by the full spelling of *mezuza* with is *gimatria* 65 (like the name mentioned in the question, alluding to the Divine Presence); and
2. protecting you from the other side and from the evil inclination, which is alluded to by the shortened spelling, since the letters of מזזות (in the 1st paragraph) can be rearranged to spell זז מות.

Interestingly, I also saw in Rav Hirsch on 6:9 that he derives *mezuza* from the root *zaz*...

---

So perhaps one can unite both of the above ideas in a single framework as follows. The first paragraph of the *Shema* is really describing a *tzaddik* (or the higher, elevated self in every person, which is deeply connected to the Divine). This is one of the reasons why reward and punishment are not mentioned and the focus of the paragraph is on loving G-d and expressing that love, which is the major motivation for the actions of a *tzaddik*. Such people exist in a place which is protected from the evil inclination (e.g., in *Tanya*, a *tzaddik* does not even have one) and so the allusion to this spells *mezuza* without a *vav*, making an allusion in that the word *mezuzos* now has letters from *zaz maves* (the 2nd idea above).

However, for a regular person, who is very much from the second paragraph of the *Shema*, the word *mezuzos* is spelled out in full to allude to the singular *mezuzah* which when spelled full is *gimatria* 65 (like the name אדנ-י), alluding to the Divine Presence being in the life of every Jew.